# Bound service not binding correctly

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-service-binding

I've looked all over the internet and cannot find a solution.

I've found a few tutorials and my code seems to match up fine, including the android dev examples.

The point of the app is to play multiple audio tracks at once, which I have done successfully and have no problem with. The problem arose when I tried to implement a service. I decided a bound service would be the best approach because having a reference to the service to use its public media player controls seemed like the best route.

What I have it doing is, in `onCreate()` a service is started with an intent. Then I call the bind service api (also in `onCreate()`) from my presenter class using the `setup()` method, which invokes `sessionPresenter.setupSounds()`. I get an error and the service doesn't seem to run at all and my app crashes.

My service reference (`serviceReference`) is null when I attempt to call my first public service method. Debugging revealed that the

`context.bindService(bindIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`

is returning true. But, the

`@Override
 public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service){...}`

is not being called. Which is were my service reference is instantiated.

I've found a few posts on StackOverflow and other places where people had a problem with `onServiceConnected` not being called, but every solution had to do with either not returning the IBinder correctly or not declaring the service in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. I'm pretty sure I'm doing those things correctly.

It's been like two whole days trying to solve this problem, please help.

The last time I posted a long question here, it turned out to be an embarrassing simple cut and paste error. I fear this may be similar, sorry if it is, but I have no choice.

Thank you to anyone who can help.

Here's the code and stack trace:

SoundSessionActivity.java

```
public class SoundSessionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ISoundSession {

private static final String TAG = "SoundSessionActivity";

private int numberOfSounds;
private RecyclerView recList;
private String sessionTitle;
private SoundSessionPresenter sessionPresenter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sound_session);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //ToDo: try to fix?

    //get the intent and retrieve the session name from it
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    sessionTitle = bundle.getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE + "NAME_OF_SESSION");
    setTitle(sessionTitle);

    //begin service
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, SoundSessionService.class);
    startService(serviceIntent);

    sessionPresenter = new SoundSessionPresenter(this,sessionTitle);
    sessionPresenter.bindSoundSessionService();

    //initializes/sets up the saved session card list
    recList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);
    recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    setup(); //this is were setupSounds() is invoked

}//onCreate


@Override
public void playPauseSwitch(final View v){
    /*sessionPresenter.playPause(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sessionPresenter.playPauseSwitch(v);
        }
    });*/


}

@Override
public void setup() {
    sessionPresenter.setupSounds(); //This is where the service referenced is called
    recList.setAdapter(sessionPresenter.getCardAdapter());

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_sound_session, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        case R.id.action_edit:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,EditSoundsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE + "NAME_OF_SESSION",sessionTitle);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


//ToDO: may need to clean stuff up here. Might not.
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //ToDo: may need to unbind from service in here
    if(isFinishing()){
        Intent stopIntent = new Intent(this,SoundSessionService.class);
        stopService(stopIntent);
    }

}


@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}
}
```

SoundSessionPresenter.java

```
public class SoundSessionPresenter {

private Context context;
private String sessionTitle;
private CardAdapter cAdapter;
private List<Integer> soundIconList;

private boolean isBound;
private SoundSessionService serviceReference;

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    //these methods never get called
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        SoundSessionService.LocalBinder mBinder = (SoundSessionService.LocalBinder) service;
        serviceReference = mBinder.getService();//serviceReference remains null
        isBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        serviceReference = null;
        isBound = false;
    }
};

//constructors
public SoundSessionPresenter(){} 

public SoundSessionPresenter(Context context,String sessionTitle){
    this.context = context;
    this.sessionTitle = sessionTitle;
}

//service api
public void bindSoundSessionService(){
    doBindToService();
}

public void unbindSoundSessionService(){
    doUnbindService();
}

private void doBindToService() {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Binding...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (!isBound) {
        Intent bindIntent = new Intent(context, SoundSessionService.class);
        isBound = context.bindService(bindIntent, mConnection,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
}

private void doUnbindService() {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Unbinding...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    clearMediaPlayers();
    context.unbindService(mConnection);
    isBound = false;
}



public void setupSounds(){
    //this is where the error is happening
    //serviceReference is null
    serviceReference.setupSounds(sessionTitle);
}

public List<Integer> getSoundList(){
    return soundIconList;
}


public void playPauseSwitch(View v){
    Activity activity = (Activity) context;
    final ImageView button = (ImageView) v;
    if(serviceReference.playPause((String) button.getTag())){
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
            }
        });
    }else{
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow);
            }
        });
    }
}

public void changeVolume(String soundName, Float newVolume){
    serviceReference.changeVolume(soundName, newVolume);
}

public void updatePlayerVolume(String soundName, float newVolume){
    serviceReference.updatePlayerVolume(soundName, newVolume);
}



public void clearMediaPlayers(){
    serviceReference.clearMediaPlayers();
}


public CardAdapter getCardAdapter(){
    cAdapter = new CardAdapter(sessionTitle);
    return cAdapter;
}
}
```

SoundSessionService.java

```
public class SoundSessionService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener{


private final String TAG = "SoundSessionService";

private final String PATH_PREFIX =
        "android.resource://com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope//" ;

private int REQUEST_CODE = 101;
private int NOTIFICATION_ID = 102;

private SoundThread sThread;
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

private Context context; //may just pass context to each methods that needs it
private static int mpCount; //may need to keep track of the number of MediaPlayers
//private String sessionTitle;//may just pass
private HashMap<String,Integer> currentSounds;// holds raw int
private List<String> soundList;// holds string name of sounds

private MyMediaPlayerPool mPool; //holds all mediaplayers used in current session


// service methods
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    soundList = new ArrayList<>();
    currentSounds = new HashMap<>();
    sThread = new SoundThread("SoundThread");
    sThread.start();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID,getNotification());

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    clearMediaPlayers();
    Thread dummy = sThread;
    sThread = null;
    dummy.interrupt();
    Toast.makeText(this,"Service being destroyed...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Log.i(TAG, "Cancelling notification");
    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onBind called");
    return mBinder;
}

//media player setup
public void setupSounds(String sessionTitle){

    //ToDo: do in other thread or asynctask

    //querying the data from the specific session
    //and use key=(String name) item=(Integer raw)

    DatabaseHelper DBHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance();
    SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    /*
    *
    *
    *  The following string resembles this query:
    *
    *  SELECT
    *  sound, raw, volume
    *  FROM
    *  sound_info INNER JOIN sounds
    *  ON
    *  sound_info.session = ?
    *  AND
    *  sound_info.sound
    *  =
    *  sounds.name
    *
    *  The result will be a table in the form of:
    *  sound|raw|volume
    *
    *  for all sounds in the current session defined by whereArgs = sessionTitle
    *
    */

    //ToDo: use volume
    String soundsInSessionQuery = DBContract.DBInfo.SELECT +
            DBContract.DBInfo.COLUMN_SOUND + DBContract.DBInfo.COMMA + DBContract.DBInfo.COLUMN_RAW + DBContract.DBInfo.COMMA +
            DBContract.DBInfo.COLUMN_VOLUME   +
            DBContract.DBInfo.FROM +
            DBContract.DBInfo.TABLE_SOUND_INFO + DBContract.DBInfo.INNER_JOIN + DBContract.DBInfo.TABLE_SOUNDS +
            DBContract.DBInfo.ON +
            DBContract.DBInfo.TABLE_SOUND_INFO + DBContract.DBInfo.DOT + DBContract.DBInfo.COLUMN_SESSION +
            DBContract.DBInfo.EQUALS + DBContract.DBInfo.Q_MARK +
            DBContract.DBInfo.AND +
            DBContract.DBInfo.TABLE_SOUND_INFO + DBContract.DBInfo.DOT + DBContract.DBInfo.COLUMN_SOUND +
            DBContract.DBInfo.EQUALS +
            DBContract.DBInfo.TABLE_SOUNDS + DBContract.DBInfo.DOT + DBContract.DBInfo.COLUMN_SOUND_NAME;

    String[] whereArgs = {sessionTitle};

    //fetches all sounds in current session
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(soundsInSessionQuery,whereArgs);

    while(c.moveToNext()){
        currentSounds.put(
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBContract.DBInfo.COLUMN_SOUND)),
                c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DBContract.DBInfo.COLUMN_RAW)) );

        soundList.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBContract.DBInfo.COLUMN_SOUND)));
    }

    db.close();
    c.close();

    createPool();

}

public void createPool(){

    sThread.doRunnable(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mPool = new MyMediaPlayerPool();
            for(String soundName:soundList){
                try{
                    String path = PATH_PREFIX + currentSounds.get(soundName);
                    MyMediaPlayer mp = new MyMediaPlayer();
                    mp.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse(path));
                    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    mp.setOnPreparedListener(SoundSessionService.this);
                    mp.setOnErrorListener(SoundSessionService.this);
                    mp.setState(State.IDLE);
                    mp.setLooping(true);
                    mPool.addMyMediaPlayer(soundName,mp);
                }catch(IOException e){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "ERROR: io exception!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                }catch(IllegalStateException e){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "ERROR: state exception!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "ERROR: illegal argument", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });

}

//media player control
public boolean playPause(String soundName){
    if(mPool.getMyMediaPlayer(soundName) == null ||
            !(mPool.getMyMediaPlayer(soundName).isPlaying()) ){
        play(soundName);
        mPool.getMyMediaPlayer(soundName).setState(State.PLAYING);
        return true;
    }else{
        pause(soundName);
        return false;
    }
}

public void play(String soundName){
    if(mPool.getMyMediaPlayer(soundName).getCurrentState() == State.PAUSED){
        mPool.getMyMediaPlayer(soundName).start();
    }else if(mPool.getMyMediaPlayer(soundName).getCurrentState() == State.IDLE){
        mPool.getMyMediaPlayer(soundName).prepareAsync();
    }
}

public void pause(String soundName){
    mPool.getMyMediaPlayer(soundName).pause();
    mPool.getMyMediaPlayer(soundName).setState(State.PAUSED);
}

public boolean isPlaying(String soundName){
    return mPool.getMyMediaPlayer(soundName).isPlaying();
}

//media player volume
public void changeVolume(String soundName, Float newVolume){
    MyMediaPlayer mp = mPool.getMyMediaPlayer(soundName);
    //sets both L and R volume to the same value
    mp.setVolume(newVolume, newVolume);
}

public float getVolume(String soundName){
    return mPool.getMyMediaPlayer(soundName).getCurrentVolume();
}

public void updatePlayerVolume(String soundName, float newVolume){
    mPool.getMyMediaPlayer(soundName).setCurrentVolume(newVolume);
}

//cleanup
public void clearMediaPlayers(){
    for(String soundName:soundList){
        mPool.getMyMediaPlayer(soundName).release();
    }
}


//notification
private Notification getNotification() {

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Service Running")
            .setTicker("Music Playing")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setOngoing(true);
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, SoundSessionActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            REQUEST_CODE, startIntent, 0);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    return notification;

}

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.start();
}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public SoundSessionService getService() {
        return SoundSessionService.this;
    }
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope">

<application
    android:name="com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope.application.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".application.view.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".application.view.SoundSessionActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".application.view.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".application.view.MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".application.view.EditSoundsActivity"> </activity>

    <service android:name=".application.presenter.mediaplayback.SoundSessionService" />

</application>
```

stack trace

```
02-15 09:51:25.571 16112-16112/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
02-15 09:51:25.571 16112-16112/? E/Zygote: v2
02-15 09:51:25.571 16112-16112/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10375
02-15 09:51:25.571 16112-16112/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
02-15 09:51:25.571 16112-16112/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SAMSUNG-SM-N910A_5.1.1 ver=38
02-15 09:51:25.581 16112-16112/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [1] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SAMSUNG-SM-N910A_5.1.1_0038
02-15 09:51:25.581 16112-16112/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
02-15 09:51:25.581 16112-16112/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
02-15 09:51:25.581 16112-16112/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-15 09:51:25.611 16112-16112/com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
02-15 09:51:25.611 16112-16112/com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
02-15 09:51:25.691 16112-16112/com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
02-15 09:51:25.761 16112-16112/com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
02-15 09:51:25.761 16112-16112/com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
02-15 09:51:25.851 16112-16112/com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope D/DatabaseHelper: DatabaseHelper instance successful
02-15 09:51:26.041 16112-16197/com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
02-15 09:51:26.061 16112-16112/com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
02-15 09:51:26.061 16112-16112/com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
02-15 09:51:26.081 16112-16112/com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope D/SRIB_DCS: log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered! 
02-15 09:51:26.081 16112-16197/com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope I/Adreno: EGLInit: QTI Build: 07/16/15, 126f54a, If3804f16ae
02-15 09:51:26.091 16112-16197/com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-15 09:51:26.101 16112-16197/com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope D/OpenGLRenderer: Get maximum texture size. GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is 16384
02-15 09:51:26.101 16112-16197/com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
02-15 09:51:26.251 16112-16112/com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1c5a7d02 time:217638745
02-15 09:51:27.451 16112-16112/com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
02-15 09:51:27.521 16112-16112/com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope time:217640012
02-15 09:51:27.551 16112-16112/com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
02-15 09:51:27.551 16112-16112/com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
02-15 09:51:27.591 16112-16112/com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-15 09:51:27.591 16112-16112/com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope, PID: 16112
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope/com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope.application.view.SoundSessionActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope.application.presenter.mediaplayback.SoundSessionService.setupSounds(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3149)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope.application.presenter.mediaplayback.SoundSessionService.setupSounds(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope.application.presenter.SoundSessionPresenter.setupSounds(SoundSessionPresenter.java:83)
                                                                                   at com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope.application.view.SoundSessionActivity.setup(SoundSessionActivity.java:86)
                                                                                   at com.firsttread.anthony.soundscope.application.view.SoundSessionActivity.onCreate(SoundSessionActivity.java:67)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experimenting a bit while I was waiting for someone to answer and got it to work.

Apparently, the problem was with the fact that I wasn't setting the binding/connection in the actual activity class. I was using my presenter class to host the code and was calling it in the activity. Even though I was using the Activity context, I think the actual ServiceConnection instance must exist in the actual activity class that is being bound to the service.

If anyone has anymore input or explanation to this problem, it would help me understand a bit more.

Comment: `android.content.ServiceConnection` is just an interface, it can be implemented anywhere, so most likely your problem is somewhere else